# Java function to calculate difference in charge?

Tags: java

This object has a max charge of 1000. And when you drain 100, and then drain 1000, the second drain is supposed to return 900. What function to use that will allow me to return 900 because that is that max amount that can be drained as you can't drain a negative number?

I tried,

```
public double drain(double minutes) {
        double drain = cameraPowerConsumption * minutes;
        batteryCharge = Math.max(batteryCharge - drain, 0);
        totalDrain += drain;
        return drain;
```

but it returns 1000 instead of 900, after already draining 100. I think the drain variable needs to be changed. Without conditionals if that matters.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to `maxCharge` and `totalDrain` in your class.  Remaining charge = maximum charge - total drain.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out I could also use Math.min. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount drained cannot be greater than the battery's remaining charge:

```java
double drain = Math.min(batteryCharge, cameraPowerConsumption * minutes);
```

After making that adjustment to your code, the rest is simple:

```java
double drain = Math.min(batteryCharge, cameraPowerConsumption * minutes);
batteryCharge -= drain;
totalDrain += drain;
return drain;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `batteryCharge` value when subtracting a larger value, you can use the ternary operator ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions_shorthand.asp)) representing `if/else`. If `batteryCharge - drain` is less than 0 then keep that value, otherwise save the substraction value. Instead use this:

```
batteryCharge = Math.max(batteryCharge - drain, 0);
```

Try this:

```
batteryCharge = batteryCharge - drain < 0 ? batteryCharge : batteryCharge - drain;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple

```
public double drain(double minutes) {
    double drain = cameraPowerConsumption * minutes;
    if (drain > batteryCharge){
        totalDrain +=batteryCharge;
        return batteryCharge;
    }
    totalDrain +=drain;
    return (batteryCharge - drain);
}
```